# C# windows form render isometric tile

Tags: c#, opengl

I know so many questions have been already asked based on this topic and still i am unable to generate tiles in isometric view.

please check the below code and its out put

```
  private void picIsometricBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        { 
            int paddingTop = sdpaddingTop.Value * -80;
            int paddingleft = sdpaddingLeft.Value * 40;
            int rotateangle = sbRotate.Value * 5;
            int noofCells = 9;
            int cellsize = 60;
            int x = 0; 
            for (int j = 1; j <= noofCells; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= noofCells; i++)
                {
                    var ep = (x % 2) == 0 ? Brushes.White : Brushes.Black;
                    int xv = (j * cellsize + paddingleft);
                    int yv = (i * cellsize) + paddingTop;
                    int xxv = (i * cellsize) + paddingleft;
                    int yyv = cellsize + paddingTop;
                    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(rotateangle);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ep, xv, yv, cellsize, cellsize);
                    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(ep, xxv, yyv, cellsize, cellsize);
                    e.Graphics.ResetTransform(); 
                    x++; 
                }
            } 
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {         
        }          
    }
```

output is rendered in picture box:

[image: out put1]

I am not sure how to generate tiles like below

[image: out put2]

Comment: Create a polygon and use  Fill/DrawPolygon and maybe TranslateTransform instead of rotating! - You have tagged OpenGL. Why?

Comment: You're probably looking for the `Skew` method instead of rotating. [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3b575a03(v=vs.110).aspx)